# how to read specific JSON files using python glob

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, wildcard, glob

i have a set of JSON files in a folder.

Sample files:

```
-2022_06_13_07_14_f71cd512135bdab9.json
-2022_06_13_07_1421_f71cd512135bdab9.json
-2022_06_13_07_12314_f71cd512135bdab9.json
-2022_06_14_132_14_f71cd512135bdab9.json
-2022_06_14_74647_14_f71cd512135bdab9.json
```

Instead of reading all files at once, I need to read them day-wise.

ex:2022_06_13_07_14_f71cd512135bdab9.json corresponding to 2022_06_13.

like wise I need to read all the JSON files and do the changes in Daywise batches.

read all JSON files in 2022_06_13 first then all the JSON files in 2022_06_14 and so on. i thought to apply wildcard with looping day wise list.

my issue with the below line. How do I add a wild card to find all JSON files related to a particular date?

```
json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, 'day*.json'))
```

current code:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 25)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25)
datelist = pd.date_range(start, end)
path_to_json = r'C:\Users\Admin\INPUT'

for a in datelist:
    day=str(a)[:10].replace('-', '_')
    json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, 'day*.json'))
    
    for i in json_files:
        with open(i,'r') as fi:
            dict = json.load(fi)
            dict[0]["Name"] = "NETFLIX"
            fi.close()
        l= i.rsplit('\\', 1)[1]
        Output_URL="C:\\Users\\Admin\\OUTPUT\\Netflix\\"+l
        with open(Output_URL, "w+") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:
`json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, 'day*.json'))`

to this:
`json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, f"{a.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')}*.json"))`

This will take date `a` and turn it into a string that is similar to the one in your files. Leave the asterisk after it as a wildcard and you should get all files that match date `a` everytime.

Comment: Thanks. Since backward slash is reserved i had to put two backward slash to set output variable. can i do it with some other way? `Output_URL="C:\\Users\\Admin\\OUTPUT\\Netflix\\"+l`

Comment: Having to put two backward slashes is quite common, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. You can use a raw string by putting `r` in front of it and that would not see that backward slash as an escape character. example: `r"Example string \ <- with a backslash"`